Kendo Style Grid draggable Item similar to datatables
I ready like the style that datatables is using for row order but I have the Kendo grid and wanted to see if I can style is similar to the blue bolder. Any help would be great.
let grid = $("#inStockProductsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
          grid.bind("dataBound", function() {
            grid._draggableRowsInstance.setOptions({
              hint: function(target) {
                const ITEMROW = "tr:not(.k-grouping-row):not(.k-detail-row):not(.k-footer-template):not(.k-group-footer):visible";

                // You can modify the hint's div element here.
                var hint = $('<div class="k-reorder-clue k-drag-clue"><span class="k-icon k-drag-status k-i-cancel"></span></div>');

                hint.css({
                  "width": "300px",
                  "background-color": "red",
                  "color": "white"
                });

                // Clone the row that is currently being dragged and remove the edit/destroy buttons if they exist.
                var clone = target.closest(ITEMROW).clone();
                clone.find("td.k-command-cell").remove();

                // Append the value of each cell to the hint.
                clone.find("td").each(function(index, elm){
                  hint.append("<span>" + elm.innerText + "&nbsp;</span>");
                });

                return hint;
              }
            });

https://dojo.telerik.com/@mcdevitt/AtihIhEj
https://dojo.telerik.com/iNoLErAx
https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/rowReorder

You can use template to recreate the hint's markup to be similar to a Grid's data row and then add the desired blue border to it.
Here is a modified example

Can I remove the right arrow and add the bolder around the row that it will replace?

What do you mean by right arrow? Currently there is an indicator for where the dragged row will be dropped. You can also set a drag event handler to the draggable instance that is being modified, find the drop target and style it - example

Yes can I replace the indicator with a gray border? It’s very hard to get it in the right location and having it at the full row may help.

You can style the target element of the dropTarget, just like in the last example. The indicator seems to be the reorderable dropCue element, so if you wish to go with that approach inspect the reorderable implementation for the rows and modify the element, it's styling and positioning calculations. If styling the drop target is sufficient, you can hide the reorderable dropCue element using a CSS rule and setting the .k-drop-hint to display: none
